# Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(...) Internal: invalid configuration argument

Tags: tensorflow

I run my code on tensorflow 2.3.0 Anaconda with CUDA Toolkit 10.1 CUDNN 7.5.0 (Windows 10) and it returns a issue

```
F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:246] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), key, counter, gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: invalid configuration argument
```

My GPU is RTX2070 and the code I am testing is

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The full results are here

```
2020-11-03 09:59:18.494825: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.388914: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2020-11-03 09:59:20.389652: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.426874: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1724] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.62GHz coreCount: 36 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-11-03 09:59:20.427039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.435227: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.437546: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.448543: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.451378: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.464548: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.472311: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.506843: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.507014: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1866] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-11-03 09:59:20.507910: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-11-03 09:59:20.508416: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1724] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.62GHz coreCount: 36 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-11-03 09:59:20.508536: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.508777: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.509056: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.509324: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.509572: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.509811: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.510030: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.510102: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2020-11-03 09:59:20.510384: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1866] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-11-03 09:59:20.952560: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1265] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-11-03 09:59:20.952716: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1271]      0
2020-11-03 09:59:20.952746: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1284] 0:   N
2020-11-03 09:59:20.953709: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1410] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6637 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-11-03 09:59:20.954420: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2020-11-03 09:59:21.179776: F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:246] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), key, counter, gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: invalid configuration argument
```

**Does any one meet this before? What are the issues and how to fix it?**

I also tested tensorflow 2.1.0, 2.2.0. Same issue happened... Thanks!

Comment: I also tried to update the CUDA to 10.2, same issue happens

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68054463/14337775

Answer (score 2):

Figured things out myself. This comes when you forget to initialize GPU.

Adding the following codes solve the problem

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

[version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7N9i.png)

maybe your version of CUDA cdunn and tensorflow is not right